# Linux distro for starting out with Bacula / AMANDA?

Tags: linux, backup, bacula

I'm interested in getting started with Bacula / AMANDA(Zmanda), and plan on setting up a Linux VM in VirtualBox to test it out.

I'd like to avoid some of the initial setup time by polling the community on distros that might be most compatible with Bacula or Amanda (I haven't yet seen a list). This will allow me to get the VirtualBox appliance up and running without trying a bunch of dead ends and having to restart the process.

**About the Network:**

Just for reference in case it helps inform the decision, our network is as follows:

- Windows based, but not on a domain
- Larger server running multiple VirtualBox VMs (development environments, etc.)
- IT Server (Conceivably where Bacula would sit)
- A NAS device (will soon be purchased -- think Drobo, etc. -- small business stuff, nothing major)

Feel free to ask any questions and I'll be happy to answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both `bacula` and `amanda` have packages in current debian stable (lenny) so it's rather unlikely to cause major problems.

Comment: +1 for Debian. Consider also the Debian-based Ubuntu, which has newer versions of Bacula and Amanda than the current Debian stable does.

Comment: `bacula` is at version 5.0.2 in lenny-backports as of 2010-11-16.

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at SME Server (wiki.contribs.org) as both are available as "add-ons" to it.